# Random output of characters from PHP barcode class

Tags: php, html, barcode

So I am using the PHP class off of http://barcode-coder.com/en/ to generate barcodes.

I get this output on my webpage:

```
GIF87a,,¡üüþüü,,,þ„Ëí£œ´Ú+Þ¼û†"£Œæ‰‚ZÊ¶î+–ðLkçz(ïþ~û ‡¿ñÈ "—Ì“± í(£ÔêäiÍB¦Ú.ëírÃä#¸\     £×º3»©~Ë_îù1nÏë÷[¾ÿ€HX˜fˆ˜˜5¨ØèHÃø(9iIy‰‰a™ÉÙé°éš *Z*IjššˆªÚÈê»+[+Gk›[†«Û«Åë,\ŒDlœüƒ¬ÜŒÃìý-]Bm‚­ÝÍÁí^.^ÞgŽ™¾>ÍîžBþ/ßM_Ÿ}_­¿Ýï¯À€É,fð`°„ {1l˜ë!ÄZ'Æªh±ÆþŒ©6r,åñc¨";‘,9 eÀ“*)±ly &¾—2Ñ¬¹ ç»›:ñìù èºŸBý-:©¹£Jí0mzê<©ÞžREcõ*™¬Z½píú,?±Ò¾’¥bö,”´j™°m{nA¹ÆÞÒb÷®¼zuðíû°CÁºþ†aø°‹ÄŠ“4–Åøñ‰È’GP®¼ ³ªËš=pîü 4HÑ¢>“¶`ú4…Ôª3´æÄúõƒØ²Ð®½à6nÝµyËöýxkáª‰Ÿ6N¹hå ™wv®:Ô«[¿Ž=»öíÜ»{ÿ>¼øñäË›?oþªôÊë%·ü¾q|Åó×'|_p~Àûþûö×ûß]Ò5 \Âu`[ ªµàY ’õ X‚5aWju¡z¸¹´á$Rõ¡T!B5bS%*u"R)µ¢P-õbO1ê4#N5Öt£L9Â´cK=ªô#JA–4¤HE~t$GIf´¤EMNô$DQ64¥BUt%AY®ÔaL]:²¥?aî3æL_‚y¦Mi*Rf=mÊóæNkæ4§!qºs';yU§}úô'!{¦3(:….hP‰þqh9ŠóèT‹5)¥•&u©‘V•©¦æ±©=Ÿ:5ê¡jsj>¥Fµ*©ZóêX­®kY³Òz+V¹î²ëV½†Që?¿z5¬Å†ue¬Á:³¬@É*ûì!Ñ3-µÕÂq-¶Ù.Ñ¬2ÝÎµm\áŽKn¹æž‹nºê®Ën»î¾o¼òÎKo½öÞ‹o¾úîËo¿þþpÀLpÁŒpÂ /ÌpÃ?qÄOLqÅ×S;
```

I am not even remotely close to figuring out why this is thrown. I got the Code 39 barcode off of dafont, and i was just using the sample test included with the php class. Is my implementation wrong or is there additional code necessary?.

```
...Code
include('barcode.php');
Code...
```

Then

```
<?php
  include('../../inc/php-barcode.php');
  $font= '../../inc/3OF9_NEW.TTF';
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                  PROPERTIES
  // -------------------------------------------------- //

  // download a ttf font here for example : http://www.dafont.com/fr/nottke.font

  // - -

  $fontSize = 10;   // GD1 in px ; GD2 in point
  $marge    = 10;   // between barcode and hri in pixel
  $x        = 125;  // barcode center
  $y        = 125;  // barcode center
  $height   = 50;   // barcode height in 1D ; module size in 2D
  $width    = 2;    // barcode height in 1D ; not use in 2D
  $angle    = 90;   // rotation in degrees : nb : non horizontable barcode might not be usable because of pixelisation

  $code     = 'abcdef4'; // barcode, of course ;)
  $type     = 'Barcode39';

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                    USEFUL
  // -------------------------------------------------- //

  function drawCross($im, $color, $x, $y){
    imageline($im, $x - 10, $y, $x + 10, $y, $color);
    imageline($im, $x, $y- 10, $x, $y + 10, $color);
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //            ALLOCATE GD RESSOURCE
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  $im     = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
  $black  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
  $white  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xff,0xff,0xff);
  $red    = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xff,0x00,0x00);
  $blue   = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0xff);
  imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 300, 300, $white);

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                      BARCODE
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  $data = Barcode::gd($im, $black, $x, $y, $angle, $type, array('code'=>$code), $width, $height);

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                        HRI
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  if ( isset($font) ){
    $box = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $data['hri']);
    $len = $box[2] - $box[0];
    Barcode::rotate(-$len / 2, ($data['height'] / 2) + $fontSize + $marge, $angle, $xt, $yt);
    imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x + $xt, $y + $yt, $blue, $font, $data['hri']);
  }


  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                    MIDDLE AXE
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  imageline($im, $x, 0, $x, 250, $red);
  imageline($im, 0, $y, 250, $y, $red);

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                  BARCODE BOUNDARIES
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){
    drawCross($im, $blue, $data['p'.$i]['x'], $data['p'.$i]['y']);
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  //                    GENERATE
  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  header('Content-type: image/gif');
  imagegif($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: That is *the image*. Are you sure the `Content-Type` header is being set correctly? Maybe there's other output before?

Comment: yeah its in a table. didn't know you had to call it on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barcode class is creating a GIF image -- it shouldn't be used in the body of your HTML page, but called separately, as from an IMG tag, similar to this:

```
<p>Here is your barcode:
<img src="/call/to/your/barcode?parm1=barcode_parm_1">
</p>
```

With this approach, you will effectively make two requests to your web server:

1. To lay out the HTML that will contain the barcode
2. To render and server the barcode

Another approach would be to construct an image file as the HTML page loads, and then reference the new file in the "src" attribute, but I inferred that you wanted the barcodes dynamically generated *always*.

If you do call it separately, make sure your PHP code is passing appropriate content headers.

Comment: ohh alright. got it. now gotta figure why it only displays a red cross. thanks!